# Appium Android : find element by element Id in Java

Tags: java, windows, testing, appium, android-5.1.1-lollipop

[image]

I tried the following APIs:

```
MobileElement book = driver.findElementById("c0cc9a86-2fbb-44d6-b288-d8c763c8a0ea");(1)
MobileElement book2 = driver.findElement(By.id("c0cc9a86-2fbb-44d6-b288-d8c763c8a0ea"));(2)
```

both don't work, (it crashed) I googled and found nothing useful, how can I get to know which API will work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -

```
MobileElement book = driver.findElementById("com.ophone.reader.ui:id/fixed_bottom_navigation_icon");(1)
MobileElement book2 = driver.findElement(By.id("com.ophone.reader.ui:id/fixed_bottom_navigation_icon"));(2)
```